# Adding webpack JS bundle to Spring/JSP WAR

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, webpack

I recently saw [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) and though I'd give it a try in a legacy project I'm working on (JSP) to streamline deploying.

I took out all .js code and turned it into a webpack project, which creates frontend_bundle.js when called with npm run dist.

Then I added a pom as per [usage instructions] (https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin#usage):

```
  <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>

        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>npm run dist</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>run dist</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
```

When I `mvn clean install' I get the whole frontend_bundle.js inside a webjar - great!

Then on the server side I include the jar as a dependency:

```
<!-- FRONTEND DEPENDENCY -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.counter</groupId>
      <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I `mvn package' I get a WAR with the frontend included inside lib/
Only problem is I can't quite link to the frontend_bundle.js in the JSP (I get 404):

WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="/webjars/counter-webapp-frontend/1.5.1/frontend_bundle.js"></script>

<h1>Maven Webpack JSP Example</h1>

<div id='inject'>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Entry point in com.example.controller package:

```
@Controller
public class BaseController extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {

    private static final String VIEW_INDEX = "index";

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/webjars/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String entryPoint(ModelMap model) {
        // return index.jsp
        return VIEW_INDEX;
    }

}
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Counter Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

context:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.controller" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Now when I deploy to maven I get a 404 logged in console for:

> GET http://localhost:8080/webjars/frontend/1.5.1/frontend_bundle.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it.

After updating web xml to use ee version 3:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0">
```

and linking to the scripts in context:

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/counter-webapp-frontend/0.0.1/vendor_bundle.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/counter-webapp-frontend/0.0.1/app_bundle.js"></script>
```

The JS scripts are loading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the webjar content explicitly to URIs as explained [here](https://www.jamesward.com/2012/04/30/webjars-in-spring-mvc)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/public**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/public/");
    }
}
```

**Edit : Thats already in the provided source**

Yes you are right, did not see that.
Other possible problems could be :

If any other webjars are mapped, the 'if' would inhibit the registration :

```
 if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/webjars/**"))
```

Set a breakpoint at the if and see, what comes accross there...

The url you use does not match the resource path :
You are mapping to

```
classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/
```

Than the url should not contain 'webjars' may be this :

```
GET http://localhost:8080/frontend/1.5.1/frontend_bundle.js
```

For sure you did, but it may be worth to double check the WAR and see if the resources are located where you expect them to....

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Stefan Isele - but (sans the annotation) isn't it exactly what I have under addResourceHandlers? I added the annotation, but this doesn't fix it just yet.